# Are theoretical questions on demography accepted on this site?

Tags: discussion

Demography is the study of populations and its dynamics, and has deep connection to politics. However, I couldn't find many questions related to demography on this site. Most of the few I found were related to political parties and voting systems.

Question: Are questions on demography accepted on this site?

*Note*: I am asking a general question, but the question I would ask is about modelization of population. Precisely, "What are the main mathematical models used in demography to modelize immigration?"

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion but IMHO it doesn't hurt to have this be on-topic. It does have a strong implication to practice of politics

Answer (score 1):

If you think it's related to politics then go ahead and ask it.

Keep in mind, however, that even if the subject matter is on-topic, the question still has to meet our other standards of quality.  It can't be too broad, or opinion-based.

The specific question you want to ask *probably* won't get closed.  If I were an expert on demography I could give a better analysis, but it does resemble a list question, and it's also a somewhat open-ended question, and open-ended questions are sometimes too broad.  Again, I'm can't be sure about this specific question because I am not an expert on the subject matter.